# How do I implement the Post Commit Hook with Trac & SVN in a Windows Environment?

Tags: windows, svn, hook, trac

I'm running in a windows environment with Trac / SVN and I want commits to the repository to integrate to Trac and close the bugs that were noted in the SVN Comment.

I know there's some post commit hooks to do that, but there's not much information about how to do it on windows.

Anyone done it successfully?  And what were the steps you followed to achive it?

Here's the hook I need to put in place in SVN, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this in the Windows environment.

[Trac Post Commit Hook](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/contrib/trac-post-commit-hook?rev=920)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, now that I've got some time to post my experience after figuring this all out, and thanks to Craig for getting me on the right track.  Here's what you need to do (at least with SVN v1.4 and Trac v0.10.3):

1. Locate your SVN repository that you want to enable the Post Commit Hook for.
2. inside the SVN repository there's a directory called hooks, this is where you'll be placing the post commit hook.
3. create a file post-commit.bat (this is the batch file that's automatically called by SVN post commit).
4. Place the following code inside the post-commit.bat file ( this will call your post commit cmd file passing in the parameters that SVN automatically passes %1 is the repository, %2 is the revision that was committed.

%~dp0\trac-post-commit-hook.cmd %1 %2

5. Now create the trac-post-commit-hook.cmd file as follows:

> @ECHO OFF
>  ::
>  :: Trac
>   post-commit-hook script for
>   Windows
>  ::
>  :: Contributed by
>   markus, modified by cboos.
>  
>  ::
>   Usage:
>  ::
>  :: 1) Insert the
>   following line in your post-commit.bat
>   script
>  ::
>  :: call
>   %~dp0\trac-post-commit-hook.cmd %1
>   %2
>  ::
>  :: 2) Check the 'Modify
>   paths' section below, be sure to set
>   at least TRAC_ENV
>  
>  
>  ::
>   ----------------------------------------------------------
>  :: Modify paths here:
>  
>  :: --
>   this one *must* be set
>  SET
>   TRAC_ENV=C:\trac\MySpecialProject
>   
>  :: -- set if Python is not in the
>   system path
>  :: SET
>   PYTHON_PATH=
>  
>  :: -- set to the
>   folder containing trac/ if installed
>   in a non-standard location 
>  :: SET
>   TRAC_PATH=
>  ::
>   ----------------------------------------------------------
>  
>  :: Do not execute hook if trac
>   environment does not exist
>  IF NOT
>   EXIST %TRAC_ENV% GOTO :EOF
>  
>   set PATH=%PYTHON_PATH%;%PATH%
>  set
>   PYTHONPATH=%TRAC_PATH%;%PYTHONPATH%
>   
>  SET REV=%2
>  
>  :: GET THE
>   AUTHOR AND THE LOG MESSAGE
>  for /F
>   %%A in ('svnlook author -r %REV% %1')
>   do set AUTHOR=%%A
>  for /F
>   "delims==" %%B in ('svnlook log -r
>   %REV% %1') do set LOG=%%B
>  
>  ::
>   CALL THE PYTHON SCRIPT
>  Python
>   "%~dp0\trac-post-commit-hook" -p
>   "%TRAC_ENV%" -r "%REV%" -u "%AUTHOR%"
>   -m "%LOG%"

The most important parts here are to set your TRAC_ENV which is the path to the repository root (SET TRAC_ENV=C:\trac\MySpecialProject)

The next MAJORLY IMPORTANT THING in this script is to do the following:

> :: GET THE AUTHOR AND THE LOG
>   MESSAGE
>    for /F %%A in ('svnlook
>   author -r %REV% %1') do set
>   AUTHOR=%%A
>    for /F "delims==" %%B
>   in ('svnlook log -r %REV% %1') do set
>   LOG=%%B

if you see in the script file above I'm using svnlook (which is a command line utility with SVN) to get the LOG message and the author that made the commit to the repository.

Then, the next line of the script is actually calling the Python code to perform the closing of the tickets and parse the log message.  I had to modify this to pass in the Log message and the author (which the usernames I use in Trac match the usernames in SVN so that was easy).

> CALL THE PYTHON SCRIPT
>  Python
>   "%~dp0\trac-post-commit-hook" -p
>   "%TRAC_ENV%" -r "%REV%" -u "%AUTHOR%"
>   -m "%LOG%"

The above line in the script will pass into the python script the Trac Environment, the revision, the person that made the commit, and their comment.

Here's the Python script that I used.  One thing that I did additional to the regular script is we use a custom field (fixed_in_ver) which is used by our QA team to tell if the fix they're validating is in the version of code that they're testing in QA.  So, I modified the code in the python script to update that field on the ticket.  You can remove that code as you won't need it, but it's a good example of what you can do to update custom fields in Trac if you also want to do that.

I did that by having the users optionally include in their comment something like:

> (version 2.1.2223.0)

I then use the same technique that the python script uses with regular expressions to get the information out.  It wasn't too bad.

Anyway, here's the python script I used, Hopefully this is a good tutorial on exactly what I did to get it to work in the windows world so you all can leverage this in your own shop...

If you don't want to deal with my additional code for updating the custom field, get the base script from this location as mentioned by Craig above ([Script From Edgewall](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/contrib/trac-post-commit-hook?rev=920))

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# trac-post-commit-hook
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2004 Stephen Hansen 
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to
# deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the
# rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or
# sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
#   The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
#   all copies or substantial portions of the Software. 
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL
# THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
# FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS
# IN THE SOFTWARE.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# This Subversion post-commit hook script is meant to interface to the
# Trac (http://www.edgewall.com/products/trac/) issue tracking/wiki/etc 
# system.
# 
# It should be called from the 'post-commit' script in Subversion, such as
# via:
#
# REPOS="$1"
# REV="$2"
# LOG=`/usr/bin/svnlook log -r $REV $REPOS`
# AUTHOR=`/usr/bin/svnlook author -r $REV $REPOS`
# TRAC_ENV='/somewhere/trac/project/'
# TRAC_URL='http://trac.mysite.com/project/'
#
# /usr/bin/python /usr/local/src/trac/contrib/trac-post-commit-hook \
#  -p "$TRAC_ENV"  \
#  -r "$REV"       \
#  -u "$AUTHOR"    \
#  -m "$LOG"       \
#  -s "$TRAC_URL"
#
# It searches commit messages for text in the form of:
#   command #1
#   command #1, #2
#   command #1 & #2 
#   command #1 and #2
#
# You can have more then one command in a message. The following commands
# are supported. There is more then one spelling for each command, to make
# this as user-friendly as possible.
#
#   closes, fixes
#     The specified issue numbers are closed with the contents of this
#     commit message being added to it. 
#   references, refs, addresses, re 
#     The specified issue numbers are left in their current status, but 
#     the contents of this commit message are added to their notes. 
#
# A fairly complicated example of what you can do is with a commit message
# of:
#
#    Changed blah and foo to do this or that. Fixes #10 and #12, and refs #12.
#
# This will close #10 and #12, and add a note to #12.

import re
import os
import sys
import time 

from trac.env import open_environment
from trac.ticket.notification import TicketNotifyEmail
from trac.ticket import Ticket
from trac.ticket.web_ui import TicketModule
# TODO: move grouped_changelog_entries to model.py
from trac.util.text import to_unicode
from trac.web.href import Href

try:
    from optparse import OptionParser
except ImportError:
    try:
        from optik import OptionParser
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError, 'Requires Python 2.3 or the Optik option parsing library.'

parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-e', '--require-envelope', dest='env', default='',
                  help='Require commands to be enclosed in an envelope. If -e[], '
                       'then commands must be in the form of [closes #4]. Must '
                       'be two characters.')
parser.add_option('-p', '--project', dest='project',
                  help='Path to the Trac project.')
parser.add_option('-r', '--revision', dest='rev',
                  help='Repository revision number.')
parser.add_option('-u', '--user', dest='user',
                  help='The user who is responsible for this action')
parser.add_option('-m', '--msg', dest='msg',
                  help='The log message to search.')
parser.add_option('-c', '--encoding', dest='encoding',
                  help='The encoding used by the log message.')
parser.add_option('-s', '--siteurl', dest='url',
                  help='The base URL to the project\'s trac website (to which '
                       '/ticket/## is appended).  If this is not specified, '
                       'the project URL from trac.ini will be used.')

(options, args) = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

if options.env:
    leftEnv = '\\' + options.env[0]
    rghtEnv = '\\' + options.env[1]
else:
    leftEnv = ''
    rghtEnv = ''

commandPattern = re.compile(leftEnv + r'(?P<action>[A-Za-z]*).?(?P<ticket>#[0-9]+(?:(?:[, &]*|[ ]?and[ ]?)#[0-9]+)*)' + rghtEnv)
ticketPattern = re.compile(r'#([0-9]*)')
versionPattern = re.compile(r"\(version[ ]+(?P<version>([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+))\)")

class CommitHook:
    _supported_cmds = {'close':      '_cmdClose',
                       'closed':     '_cmdClose',
                       'closes':     '_cmdClose',
                       'fix':        '_cmdClose',
                       'fixed':      '_cmdClose',
                       'fixes':      '_cmdClose',
                       'addresses':  '_cmdRefs',
                       're':         '_cmdRefs',
                       'references': '_cmdRefs',
                       'refs':       '_cmdRefs',
                       'see':        '_cmdRefs'}

    def __init__(self, project=options.project, author=options.user,
                 rev=options.rev, msg=options.msg, url=options.url,
                 encoding=options.encoding):
        msg = to_unicode(msg, encoding)
        self.author = author
        self.rev = rev
        self.msg = "(In [%s]) %s" % (rev, msg)
        self.now = int(time.time()) 
        self.env = open_environment(project)
        if url is None:
            url = self.env.config.get('project', 'url')
        self.env.href = Href(url)
        self.env.abs_href = Href(url)

        cmdGroups = commandPattern.findall(msg)


        tickets = {}

        for cmd, tkts in cmdGroups:
            funcname = CommitHook._supported_cmds.get(cmd.lower(), '')

            if funcname:

                for tkt_id in ticketPattern.findall(tkts):
                    func = getattr(self, funcname)
                    tickets.setdefault(tkt_id, []).append(func)

        for tkt_id, cmds in tickets.iteritems():
            try:
                db = self.env.get_db_cnx()

                ticket = Ticket(self.env, int(tkt_id), db)
                for cmd in cmds:
                    cmd(ticket)

                # determine sequence number... 
                cnum = 0
                tm = TicketModule(self.env)
                for change in tm.grouped_changelog_entries(ticket, db):
                    if change['permanent']:
                        cnum += 1

                # get the version number from the checkin... and update the ticket with it.
                version = versionPattern.search(msg)
                if version != None and version.group("version") != None:
                    ticket['fixed_in_ver'] = version.group("version")

                ticket.save_changes(self.author, self.msg, self.now, db, cnum+1)
                db.commit()

                tn = TicketNotifyEmail(self.env)
                tn.notify(ticket, newticket=0, modtime=self.now)
            except Exception, e:
                # import traceback
                # traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stderr)
                print>>sys.stderr, 'Unexpected error while processing ticket ' \
                                   'ID %s: %s' % (tkt_id, e)


    def _cmdClose(self, ticket):
        ticket['status'] = 'closed'
        ticket['resolution'] = 'fixed'

    def _cmdRefs(self, ticket):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 5:
        print "For usage: %s --help" % (sys.argv[0])
    else:
        CommitHook()
```

Answer (score 4):

Benjamin's answer is close, but on Windows you need to give the hook script files an executable extension, such as .bat or .cmd. I use .cmd. You can take the template scripts, which are unix shell scripts, shell scripts and convert them to .bat/.cmd syntax.

But to answer the question of integrating with Trac, follow these steps.

1. Ensure that Python.exe is on the system path. This will make your life easier.
2. Create post-commit.cmd in \hooks folder. This is the actual hook script that Subversion will execute on the post-commit event.

   ```
   @ECHO OFF

   :: POST-COMMIT HOOK
   ::
   :: The post-commit hook is invoked after a commit.  Subversion runs
   :: this hook by invoking a program (script, executable, binary, etc.)
   :: named 'post-commit' (for which this file is a template) with the 
   :: following ordered arguments:
   ::
   ::   [1] REPOS-PATH   (the path to this repository)
   ::   [2] REV          (the number of the revision just committed)
   ::
   :: The default working directory for the invocation is undefined, so
   :: the program should set one explicitly if it cares.
   ::
   :: Because the commit has already completed and cannot be undone,
   :: the exit code of the hook program is ignored.  The hook program
   :: can use the 'svnlook' utility to help it examine the
   :: newly-committed tree.
   ::
   :: On a Unix system, the normal procedure is to have 'post-commit'
   :: invoke other programs to do the real work, though it may do the
   :: work itself too.
   ::
   :: Note that 'post-commit' must be executable by the user(s) who will
   :: invoke it (typically the user httpd runs as), and that user must
   :: have filesystem-level permission to access the repository.
   ::
   :: On a Windows system, you should name the hook program
   :: 'post-commit.bat' or 'post-commit.exe',
   :: but the basic idea is the same.
   :: 
   :: The hook program typically does not inherit the environment of
   :: its parent process.  For example, a common problem is for the
   :: PATH environment variable to not be set to its usual value, so
   :: that subprograms fail to launch unless invoked via absolute path.
   :: If you're having unexpected problems with a hook program, the
   :: culprit may be unusual (or missing) environment variables.
   :: 
   :: Here is an example hook script, for a Unix /bin/sh interpreter.
   :: For more examples and pre-written hooks, see those in
   :: the Subversion repository at
   :: http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/ and
   :: http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/

   setlocal

   :: Debugging setup
   :: 1. Make a copy of this file.
   :: 2. Enable the command below to call the copied file.
   :: 3. Remove all other commands
   ::call %~dp0post-commit-run.cmd %* > %1/hooks/post-commit.log 2>&1

   :: Call Trac post-commit hook
   call %~dp0trac-post-commit.cmd %* || exit 1

   endlocal
   ```
3. Create trac-post-commit.cmd in \hooks folder:

   ```
   @ECHO OFF
   ::
   :: Trac post-commit-hook script for Windows
   ::
   :: Contributed by markus, modified by cboos.

   :: Usage:
   ::
   :: 1) Insert the following line in your post-commit.bat script
   ::
   :: call %~dp0\trac-post-commit-hook.cmd %1 %2
   ::
   :: 2) Check the 'Modify paths' section below, be sure to set at least TRAC_ENV

   setlocal

   :: ----------------------------------------------------------
   :: Modify paths here:

   :: -- this one *must* be set
   SET TRAC_ENV=D:\projects\trac\membershipdnn

   :: -- set if Python is not in the system path
   SET PYTHON_PATH=

   :: -- set to the folder containing trac/ if installed in a non-standard location
   SET TRAC_PATH=
   :: ----------------------------------------------------------

   :: Do not execute hook if trac environment does not exist
   IF NOT EXIST %TRAC_ENV% GOTO :EOF

   set PATH=%PYTHON_PATH%;%PATH%
   set PYTHONPATH=%TRAC_PATH%;%PYTHONPATH%

   SET REV=%2

   :: Resolve ticket references (fixes, closes, refs, etc.)
   Python "%~dp0trac-post-commit-resolve-ticket-ref.py" -p "%TRAC_ENV%" -r "%REV%"

   endlocal
   ```
4. Create trac-post-commit-resolve-ticket-ref.py in \hooks folder. I used [the same script from EdgeWall](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/trunk/contrib/trac-post-commit-hook?rev=920), only I renamed it to better clarify its purpose.

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a shot today and let you all know how that went.  I'll post back here with anything that I run into. If this works great I'll mark it as the answer tomorrow.

Thanks, this looks very detailed!

Answer (score 0):

Post commit hooks live in the "hooks" directory where ever you have the repository living on the server side.  I don't know where you have them in your environment, so this is just an example

e.g. (windows):

```
C:\Subversion\repositories\repo1\hooks\post-commit
```

e.g. (llinux/unix):

```
/usr/local/subversion/repositories/repo1/hooks/post-commit
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I'll add "Code Monkey's Answer is PERFECT" - is to be wary of this (my mistake)

```
:: Modify paths here:

:: -- this one must be set
SET TRAC_ENV=d:\trac\MySpecialProject

:: -- set if Python is not in the system path
:: SET PYTHON_PATH=**d:\python**

:: -- set to the folder containing trac/ if installed in a non-standard location 
:: SET TRAC_PATH=**d:\python\Lib\site-packages\trac**
```

I hadn't set the Non-System paths and took me a while to see the obvious :D

Just match sure no-one else makes the same mistake! Thanks Code Monkey! 1000000000 points :D

Answer (score 0):

First a big thanks to Code Monkey!

However, it's important to get the right python script depending on your trac version. To get the appropriate version, SVN check out the folder:

http://svn.edgewall.com/repos/trac/branches/**xxx**-stable/contrib

where **xxx** corresponds to the trac version you're using, for instance: 0.11

Otherwise you'll get a post-commit error that looks like this:

commit failed (details follow): MERGE of '/svn/project/trunk/web/directory/': 200 OK

Answer (score 0):

For all Windows users who wants to install newest trac (0.11.5):
Follow the instructions on Trac's site named TracOnWindows.

Download 32bit 1.5 Python even if You have 64bit Windows. 
   note: I saw somewhere instructions how to compile trac to work natively on 64bit system.

When You install all that is required go to the repository folder. There is folder hooks.
Inside it put files Code Monkey mentioned, but dont create "trac-post-commit-resolve-ticket-ref.py" like he did. Take advice from Quant Analyst and do like he said:

"However, it's important to get the right python script depending on your trac version. To get the appropriate version, SVN check out the folder:
http://svn.edgewall.com/repos/trac/branches/xxx-stable/contrib
where xxx corresponds to the trac version you're using, for instance: 0.11"

From there downoad file "trac-post-commit-hook" and put it in hooks folder.

Edit these lines in trac-post-commit.cmd

> SET PYTHON_PATH="Path to python installation folder"
>
> SET TRAC_ENV="Path to folder where you
>   did tracd initenv"

Remember no last \ !!!

I have removed quotes from last line -r "%REV%" to be -r %REV% but i dont know if this is needed. This will not work now ( at least on my win 2008 server ), because hook will fail ( commit will go ok). This got to do with permissions. By default permissions are restricted and we need to allow python or svn or trac ( whatever i dont know ) to change trac information. So go to your trac folder,project folder,db folder, right click trac.db and choose properties. Go to the security tab and edit permissions to allow everyone full control. This isn't so secure but i wasted all day on this security matter and i don't want to waste another just to find for which user you should enable permissions.

Hope this helps....