# Post-Commit Hook with Trac

Tags: svn, trac, visualsvn

So I followed the instructions of the great post left here [Post Commit Hook with Trac and SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113010/post-commit-hook-with-trac-and-svn) and the associated posts mentioned for Trac + VisualSVN on windows.

I have set everything up - and when I run the "post-commit.cmd" - I get no errors at all.

My problem is - that Trac does not update tickets after I submit a commit and I cannot figure out why ?

Does anyone have any ideas how I can somehow figure out why its not updating Tickets from the SVN ?

**Edit:** So I turned Logging on in Trac - and when I run the post-commit.cmd script from the hooks folder i get

**Trac[svn_fs] DEBUG: Subversion bindings imported**

But no tickets update?

Answer (score 1):

First question -- the post you reference (not yours), mentions issuing the comment "#1 fixed.", which I think will fail.  If you're using that syntax as well, have you tried "Fixed #1.", which is the correct order for the regex which parses comments?

If it's not that simple, I've got no direct experience with the default script -- I use the one associated with the Timing and Estimation plugin -- but, I'd start by swiping some code from the T&E plugin:

```
logfile = "/var/trac/commithook.log"
LOG = False

if LOG:
    f = open (logfile,"w")
    f.write("Begin Log\n")
    f.close()
    def log (s, *params):
        f = open (logfile,"a")
        f.write(s % params)
        f.write("\n")
        f.close()
else:
    def log (s, *params):
        pass
```

with appropriate modifications for your environment; then insert some logging.

The only problem I've ever run into was an update to the T&E script which lost case-insensitivity, long ago resolved.  That doesn't look like an issue with the base script, though.