# Using python scripts in subversion hooks on windows

Tags: python, windows, svn, hook, svn-hooks

My main goal is to get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84178/how-do-i-implement-the-post-commit-hook-with-trac-svn-in-a-windows-environment) up and running.

My hook gets called when I do the commit with Tortoise SVN, but it always exits when I get to this line: Python "%~dp0trac-post-commit-hook.py" -p "%TRAC_ENV%" -r "%REV%" || EXIT 5

If I try and replace the call to the python script with any simple Python script it still doesn't work so I'm assuming it is a problem with the call to Python and not the script itself.

I have tried setting the PYTHON_PATH variable and also set %PATH% to include Python.

I have trac up and running so Python is working on the server itself.

Here is some background info:

- Python is installed on Windows server and script is called from local machine so

  IF NOT EXIST %TRAC_ENV% EXIT 3

  and

  SET PYTHON_PATH=X:\Python26
  IF NOT EXIST %PYTHON_PATH% EXIT 4

fail unless I point set them to the mapped network drive (That is point them at X and Y drives not C and E drives)

- Python scripts can be called anywhere from the command line from the server regardless of the drive so the PATH variable should be set correctly

Appears to be an issue with calling python scripts externally, but not sure how I go about changing the permissions for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the following things into account:

- network drive mappings and `subst`
  mappings are user specific. Make sure
  the drives exist for the user account
  under which the svn server is
  running.
- subversion hook scripts are [run
  without any environment variables
  being set](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks) for security reasons, not even `%path%`. Call
  the python executable with an
  absolute path, e.g.
  `c:\python25\python.exe`.

Comment: Thanks wcoenen.

I wasn't getting the fact that %path% wasn't being set. I finally realised this when I went to the mapped drive and tried calling Python which told me it couldn't find a specific dll. Which obviously was not available since %path% isn't set.

Now the scipt is being called (although it still has a couple of issues) and should be sorted soon.

Thanks again.

Comment: i have the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54356967/how-to-call-a-python-script-in-visualsvn-server-precommit-hook-running-on-window