# How to require adding meta file in VisualSVN Server,Pre-commit hook?

Tags: svn, unity-game-engine, visualsvn-server

We are working on unity engine for mobile game, 
I need visualSVN pre-commit hook script for artist who every time missing meta file when added new assets.

How can I configure the server to require meta file to be non-meta file at new file adding to SVN commit?

Comment: Write your pre-commit hook script. You can freely find hook script examples in various programming languages on the web. I'd suggest trying Python.

Comment: @bahrep can you explain more detail? how can I excute python at hook script, pls help newbie :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the latest VisualSVN Server 3.5 that includes Python 2.7 bindings for Subversion.
2. Write a [pre-commit hook script](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/reposhooks/pre-commit/) in Python that will reject invalid commits and allow proper ones. Search for hook examples on the web. Here is an example: [how to write a svn hook script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773678/how-to-write-a-svn-hook-script) & [Using python scripts in subversion hooks on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135499/using-python-scripts-in-subversion-hooks-on-windows) and much much more.