# How to call a python script in visualsvn server precommit hook running on windows

Tags: python, windows, svn, visualsvn-server, pre-commit-hook

I Implement a python script for the pre-commit hook to detect the commit message, author, changed path then throw exception or error in specifics cases.

I want to set this script pre-commit.py in the VisualSVN server Pre-commit Hook
using this command in the Hooks

```
C:\Users\momo\Desktop\pre-commit.py %1 %2
```

When I want to commit I got this  error `Access Denied` looks like pre-commit hook doesn't recognize my syntax

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python scripts are not considered as executable files on Windows. You should wrap them around in Windows Batch. For example, a pre-commit hook script can look as follows:

```
set REPOS-PATH=%1
set TXN-NAME=%2
"C:\Python27\python.exe" "C:\Repositories\MyRepository\hooks\pre-commit.py" %REPOS-PATH% %TXN-NAME%
```

This Windows Batch script will run Python script located at `C:\Repositories\MyRepository\hooks\post-commit.py` and will pass the `%1` and `%2` arguments.

Put this code into your repository's `\hooks\pre-commit.bat` or `\hooks\pre-commit.cmd` file manually or via the VisualSVN Server Manager console:

1. Start the **VisualSVN Server Manager** console.
2. Right-click a repository and click **Properties**.
3. Click the **Hooks** tab.
4. Click the **Pre-commit** hook and click **Edit**.

Comment: I still have the same error please have a look in picture

Comment: 1. The hook editor windows should have the content that you now see in Notepad++. 2. Copy the python script file from your Desktop directory to your repository's hooks directory (e.g. C:\Repositories\MyRepo\hooks\) and adjust paths accordingly. 3. Make sure that the VisualSVN Server service account has permissions to all files involved including python.exe.

Comment: how can check the VisualSVN Server service account has permissions to all files involved including python.exe?

Comment: Use the `services.msc` or run the `sc qc visualsvnserver` command to see the name of the service account SERVICE_START_NAME. The account is **Network Service**, by default. The see the NTFS permissions use the **Get-Acl** PowerShell cmdlet or Windows File Explorer: http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-setting.htm

Comment: do you know how to list specific directories in the SVN pre-commit? I'm using `svn list [repor_path]` but this command doesn't work in the pre-commit hook how I deal with it using `svnlook` command?

Comment: I guess that you want to try `svnlook dirs-changed` - http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnlook.c.dirs-changed.html Please, ask a new question - do not use existing Q/A threads for new questions.